# I am trying to write a trigger which is partially working

Tags: triggercontext, before-trigger, trigger, trigggers

Trying to create order -->Order package and order lineitem..when opp is closed won  please find comments in code to understand issue.

```
  trigger CreateOrder1 on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
    Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> OrderIds=new Set<Id>();
    List <Order> OrderToInsert = new List <Order>(); 
    Set<Id> quotepackageIds= new Set<Id>();
    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
    List<Order> orderListNew = new List<Order>();
    List<Quote_Package__c> qp=new List<Quote_Package__c>();
    Map<Id,Id> OpportunityPricebook2=new Map<Id,Id>();

    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
      if (o.StageName=='Won') {          
        Order ord = new Order(); 
        ord.AccountId= o.AccountId; 
        ord.Status='Draft';
        ord.opportunityid=o.id; 
        ord.EffectiveDate=system.today(); 
        ord.pricebook2id=o.pricebook2id;  
        ord.CurrencyIsoCode=o.CurrencyIsoCode; 
        OrderToInsert.add(ord); 
        OrderIds.add(ord.id); 
        opportunityIds.add(o.id);    
      }

    insert OrderToInsert ; 
  }

  system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+OrderIds);  //Ids are coming null .I need this ids in-order to insert order package.Please checkout below comment
  for(Opportunity o1 : Trigger.old){
    if(o1.StageName=='Won'){
      opportunityIds.add(o1.Id);
    }
  }  

  Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsWithLineItems = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Description,Quote_Package__c,Id,ListPrice,PriceBookEntryId,Name,OpportunityId,Product2Id,ProductCode,Quantity,TotalPrice,UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id IN :opportunityIds]);
  if(opportunityIds.size() > 0){
    // Loop through orders
    List<OrderItem> orderItemsForInsert = new List<OrderItem>();
    for(Order o : OrderToInsert){
      // For each order get the related opportunity and line items, loop through the line items and add a new order line item to the order line item list for each matching opportunity line item
      Opportunity oppWithLineItem = oppsWithLineItems.get(o.OpportunityId);             
      for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oppWithLineItem.OpportunityLineItems){
        if(oli.Quote_Package__c!=null){

          quotepackageIds.add(oli.Quote_Package__c);

        }

        orderItemsForInsert.add(new OrderItem(Quantity=oli.Quantity,UnitPrice=oli.UnitPrice,PriceBookEntryId=oli.PriceBookEntryId,OrderId=o.Id));
      }
    }

    if(orderItemsForInsert.size() > 0){
      insert orderItemsForInsert;
    }
    if(quotepackageIds.size()>0){

      qp=[SELECT Display_Price_As__c,Id,Name,OwnerId,Package__c,Physchem_Subpackage__c,Quote__c,SBU__c,SystemModstamp,Total_Price__c FROM Quote_Package__c where id in:quotepackageIds];

    }

    orderListNew =[SELECT AccountId,EffectiveDate,OpportunityId,OrderNumber,OriginalOrderId,Pricebook2Id,TotalAmount FROM Order where id in:OrderIds ];//Here m passing orderIds to this query i don't understant why it is coming null.
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@'+orderListNew .size());

    for (Quote_Package__c qop:qp){
      for(Order opc : orderListNew){

        Order_Package__c ord =new Order_Package__c();
        ord.name=qop.name;
        ord.order__c=opc.Id;
        ord.currencyisocode=qop.currencyisocode;

        insert ord;
      }           
    }        
  }    
}
```

Comment: It is much easier for forum members to help answer your question if you pose it as text instead of burying it in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add the Id of an Order to `OrderIds` before you insert the orders.

sObjects don't have Ids before you insert them*

I'd suggest taking your `insert OrderToInsert;` DML statement outside of the for loop.

Then, after you insert your new orders, loop through your `OrderToInsert` list, and add the Ids to `OrderIds` at that point.

*Well...they can if you specify the Id as an argument when you call `new <sObject api name>()`...but this is not what you want to do in this situation